# Getting the percentage of the current month on the past 3 months in Google Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to use Google Looker Studio's Scorecard or Table to show the percentage of Net Profit for the current month over the previous three months. I tried creating a calculated field but I still can not figure it out on how I will do it.

It should like this as

2,500 + 2,000 + 1,500 = 6,000

(1,000/6,000)*100 = 16.67% for January 2024

| Date | Profit | Past 3 Month Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 | 1,000 | 16.67% |
| 12/1/2023 | 2,500 | 15% |
| 11/1/2023 | 2,000 | 12% |
| 10/1/2023 | 1,500 | 11% |

DATE -  my variable name for dates

I tried this code : `AVG(NetProfit, DATETIME_ADD(DATE, INTERVAL -3 month))` but it's wrong.